# Why this match fail?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd7RG/1/) code :

```
var tlTemp=new Array();

tlTemp.push("00 - 01:??:?? - TL 1");
tlTemp.push("00 - 12:??:?? - TL 2");

for(i=0; i<tlTemp.length; i++) {
    var removedTL = tlTemp[i].match(/^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)/);

    if(removedTL!=null) {
        alert("ok");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no");
        return;
    }
}
```

and I don't understand why first string print ok and the second (so similar) no. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate part of the regexp that defines the different part of the string is:

```
(\?\?|10|0\d)
```

It matches:

```
??
10
0x   where x is a digit
```

So 12 does not match.

Now, also there is `TL 2` instead of `TL 1` but in the regexp this is defined as:

```
(.*)
```

which matches everything so that is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because your regular expression explicitly excludes it.

This section:

```
/^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d)
```

constrains matches to strings starting with two digits, a space, a dash, and a space, and then either "??", "10", or "0" followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your regular expression: `(\?\?|10|0\d)` should be changed to `(\?\?|10|\d\d)`. The zero is changed to a \d. in the first string, that part of the string is `01`, while the second string has `12`, not matching the regular expression.